# Sheet opening unattached to window

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-sheet

I have a problem with a sheet that when opened for the first time, will open unattached to the window.  After dismissing it, then the sheet works as it should.

Here is the code that I am starting the sheet with:

```
- (IBAction)addButtonAction:(id)sender {

    assert ([editorController window]);
    assert (window);

    [NSApp beginSheet: [editorController window]
       modalForWindow: window 
        modalDelegate: editorController 
       didEndSelector: @selector(didEndSheet:returnCode:contextInfo:) 
          contextInfo: nil]; 
}
```

The variables 'window' and 'editorController' are initialized in the application delegate header file as @private.

The 'didEndSelector' is defined in the 'editorController' code file and is called when the window is closed.

The code for the 'didEndSelector' is as follows:

```
- (void)didEndSheet:(NSWindow *)sheet returnCode:(int)returnCode contextInfo:(void *)contextInfo
{
    [sheet orderOut:self];
}
```

The window is cancelled with a call to selector 'cancelButtonAction' which is as follows:

```
- (IBAction)cancelButtonAction:(id)sender {
    [NSApp endSheet:self.window];
}
```

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the "visible at launch" option on the NSWindow in the xib file isn't turned on.